# How to change multiple .csv file contents with python

Tags: python, csv

I want to sort all CSV column labels at once, like this.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYyYp.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj6CT.png)

How to deal with the problem of writing multiple csv QQ.

Now I can only organize one file at a time, I try to write in a loop but keep getting errors

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Try looking at [?odifying multiple .csv files from same directory in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292999/modifying-multiple-csv-files-from-same-directory-in-python).